# What's wrong in "Since the last explore voyages into space, we have increased our knowledge about the planet Jupiter"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

> Since the last explore voyages into space, we have increased our knowledge about the planet 
>   Jupiter.

Why is *explore* incorrect? Could you please explain it?

Comment: I'm assuming you're getting these from some sort of practice exam. If so, you might want to explain that in your question (that would help explain why you're suggesting these four words, as opposed to, say, "a. last b. explore c. knowledge d. Jupiter"). You might also want to elaborate on _why_ you are confused. You're welcome to ask for assistance here, but, on the Stack Exchange network, it's generally assumed that those asking questions will put forth a good-faith effort to solve the problem themselves, and, if unable to do so, at least clarify where the confusion is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's wrong because *explore* is a verb, but it has to be an adjective in this sentence:

> Since the last **exploratory** voyages into space, we have increased our knowledge about the planet Jupiter.

That's the grammatically correct sentence.

Comment: At first I thought maybe it was just me, but according to Google Books, we prefer [our knowledge **of** Jupiter](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22our+knowledge+of+jupiter%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) over [our knowledge **about** Jupiter](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22our+knowledge+about+Jupiter%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) by 1450 to 5. I doubt anyone would expect a learner to pick up on that distinction, so if OP got this from an "exam" context, I don't think much of the people who set the question.

Comment: @Fumble: Of versus about is merely a style choice, though. Test makers are always making mistakes. Even the pros make howlers.

Comment: You might as well say most grammar is merely a matter of style until the less-favoured variants become so irritating we say they're no longer acceptable. I would certainly expect setters to be aware of such marked preferences, and avoid really uncommon variants.

Comment: @Fumble: I checked COCA and the ratio there is only 5 to 1 (12685:2323), so in AmE, it _of_ isn't such a pronounced preference. Now, **this tells you and I** (and there's a perfect example of preference & style determining what's good grammar, according to the _CGEL_, despite my belief that it's a solecism) that there's no big deal here. Testers are biased too.

Comment: Well, there is such a thing as flogging a dead horse, and I do realise GB has its limitations. But it seems to support my thinking that if you have knowledge *about* something (which is less common anyway), that something is usually a broad field. When it's a single thing (such as Jupiter) *of* becomes even more likely. But I admit we're all biased, and my first comment was putting it a bit strong.

Comment: @Fumble: I don't make any qualitative distinctions between BrE & AmE, or, for that matter, between any of the national flavors favored in the Anglophone countries. I prefer to write & speak AmE because it's my mother tongue, & I love to read & listen to other varieties because they're interesting & _sometimes & in some ways (intentional vagueness here)_ better & more aesthetically pleasing.

Comment: I'll have to watch that one, I meant Google Books, not Great Britain!

Comment: @Fumble: Sorry about my misunderstanding. Just goes to prove that readers cannot read one's mind, though, so it was a useful toe-stubbing.